# How can my jQuery dialog button execute my code behind?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog, server-side

`enter code here`My jquery ui dialog contains an iframe and has the option of two buttons, apply and close. 
Here is my javascript generating this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('<iframe id="PDFDialog"  frameborder="0" src="' + this.href + '" />').dialog({
            title: ($this.attr('title')) ? $this.attr('title') : 'External Site',
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 700,
            height: 600,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            buttons: {
                Apply: function () {
                    $("#<%= applyHiddenBtn%>").click();                        
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }).width(650).height(550);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Im not sure how to execute my code behind that i have prepared for the dialog button "Apply". As an attempt i have this other server button `<asp:Button runat="server" ID="applyHiddenBtn" OnClick="applyHiddenBtn_Click"/>` that i try firing at the same time.

The goal is to fire this:

```
Sub applyHiddenBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    lblTest1.Text = "HelloWorld!!!1!"
End Sub
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will execute a `POST` to the server executing the handler for your `applyHiddenBtn`:

```
__doPostBack('applyHiddenBtn', '');
```

---

http://weblogs.asp.net/yousefjadallah/archive/2010/06/27/insure-that-dopostback-function-implemented-on-the-page.aspx

Comment: does the post back properly but doesn`t fire my code behind :/. Am i suppose to insert __doPostBack('applyHiddenBtn', ''); under $("#applyHiddenBtn").click();?

Comment: another question: should i simply write my targets name ('applyHiddenBtn','') or should i add this ('<%= applyHiddenBtn%>','')